# Giving focus to <select> elements in Mobile IE (WP8)

Tags: jquery, html, select, focus, windows-phone

I'm working on a HTML 5 based web application, that will eventually be deployed to iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8 (possibly 7, too)

One part of the application involves the user selecting options from a `select` drop down menu.

Because these form elements aren't very stylable, I've come up with a solution where I have the CSS move the `select` elements to an absolute position, -10000px from the top, so that they don't show up in the app.

The app. then inserts an `a` element in it's place, which is styled to look like a simple block with the currently selected value written inside it.

When the user taps the `a` element, I'm using jQuery (2.0) to intercept the tap and set the focus to the `select` element, thus bringing up the normal selection mechanism used in the web browser.

This works flawlessly on iOS. Haven't tried it on Android yet, but it doesn't work at all in Windows Phone 8's IE.

Is there any known workaround for this? Is it just that IE isn't giving the focus to the select, or is it giving focus but not opening the selection menu?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know jQuery 2.0 does not work in IE > 8

> Remember that jQuery 2.0 will not run on IE 6, 7, or 8; we’re saving
>   that duty for jQuery 1.9. We fully expect that most Internet web sites
>   may continue to use jQuery 1.x for quite a while, as long as older
>   versions of IE still comprise a large proportion of web surfers. And
>   so the jQuery team will also continue to support both the jQuery 1.x
>   and 2.x lines. Don’t feel like you’re missing something or falling
>   behind by using 1.9 on your web site, since the APIs for 1.9 and 2.0
>   are the same.

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/

Comment: Windows Phone 8 uses IE 10, as far as I know, so jQuery 2.0 should work fine with it as I understand.

Other parts of the code that use jQuery work fine, so I'm not sure it's that that's the issue - I might try it with jQuery 1.9 though, cheers.

Comment: Switching to jQuery 1.9 actually breaks the app. entirely, which I'm surprised about - didn't think I'd used any 2.0 specific features. I know what I'll be doing tonight!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't discovered the root cause of this issue, but have worked around it by instead using normal `select` elements and styling them with CSS.

To avoid having the drop-down arrow button visible, I've used `jQuery.wrap()` to wrap the `select` elements in `div` elements, styled how I want with the `select` elements wider than the `div`, i.e.:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}

div select {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 150px; /* wider than the div, to hide the drop-down arrow */
}
```